# Problem on $L^2$ spaces.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ converging uniformly to $f$ a.e. on a set of finite measure. I would like to prove that this implies $f_n\rightarrow f$ in the $L^2$ norm.

Attempt: $f_n\rightarrow f$ on $[0,1]$ except on a set (say $E$) of finite measure. Then given $\epsilon>0 $ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]\backslash E$ and $n\geq N$.

To prove $||f_n-f||_2\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$:
$||f_n-f||_2^2=\int_0^1 |f_n-f|^2dx=\int_E|f_n-f|^2 dx+\int_{E^c}|f_n-f|^2dx$

After that I'm not sure how to proceed, help me!

Since integral over finite set having  finite Lebesgue measure 0 then first integral is 0. For second integral apply uniformly continuity on [0,1] \E. Can I do like that. Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: What is the underlying space?

Answer (score 0):

$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon \\ |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2<\epsilon ^2 \\ \int_0^1|f_n(x)-f(x)|^2<\epsilon ^2 
$$